Как проскроллить выпадающий список до определенного элемента и выбрать его с помощью Selenium?
Есть сайт: https://artists.kzn.ru
Нужно из списка "Расписание по адресу" выбрать адрес 'Дом татарской кулинарии ул.Баумана №31/12', то есть проскроллить до него и кликнуть.
Смог найти решение как прокрутить саму страницу в самый низ, но как проскролить элементы выпадающего списка определенного адреса — не понимаю.
После нужно будет выбрать дату, время и выполнить бронирование.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://artists.kzn.ru')
time.sleep(5)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'time-table__option').click()


Вам надо с помощью Selenium не страницу прокручивать, а открывать список по кнопке и выбирать элемент по XPath.

@Chaos_Sower Насколько я понимаю могу использовать id="list-item-98-27", то есть выполнять driver.find_element(By.ID, 'list-item-98-27').click()
Но элемент не найден, так как возможно список подгружается именно при скролле. То есть на старте этого элемента еще нет.
Так же меня смущает использовать фиксированный id, в теории он может изменится со временем

https://api.artists.kzn.ru/api/events/62?date=2024-09-12
